# Ionic cordova plugins by android version

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to know if there any website or anyone know how to know which cordova plugins version are for android 5.0.0. Because when I try to build android 5.0.0 with newest plugins it throws errors, that these plugins are not in that android version.

For example :

```
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2,14,0 - android 7.1.0 working
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2,14,0 - android 5.0 not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the latest cordova platform plugin. At the moment is the version 7.X.X and 6.X.X

cordova-android

7.X.X -> 4.4 ~ 8.1 Android version

6.X.X -> 4.1 ~ 8.0 Android version

Table of equivalence cordova-android to [range of android version](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support):

Using the version 6 or 7 you will cover the android 5 and will work with the most of the plugins. The 7.X.X version have a breaking change with the [old plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html).

If you use some old plugins you will stick with the 6.X.X. If not it's preferable the 7.X.X .

For more information: https://cordova.apache.org/blog/